# Superlight database or MultiValueMap on disk rather than RAM?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have to store pairs like `{long key, long value}` and there could be multiple values per one key. I need to effectively enumerate keys and effectively search for values for a given key.

MultiValueMap seems to be a perfect solution but I am going to have billions of records, so it is not possible to keep them in RAM.

What could be the best file system replacement for MultiValueMap? What is the best simple but fast key-value database for Java?

Comment: Its likely to be one of these database http://nosql-database.org/  BTW, you can keep billions of 16 byte record in memory. Its just a matter of money.

Comment: For about $11K you can buy a server with 192 GB of memory, enough for up to 11 billion entries (not including indexes) For double the price, you can get double the memory. ;)

Comment: Right. How can you make JVM work with -Xmx192G ? :)

Comment: Use a 64-bit JVM. ;) Obviously you have to leave a few GB for the OS. I would use `-mx192g` as the shorter version of the same option.

Comment: For around $40K you can get a server 512 MB and $70K you can get 1 TB of main memory in a server. None of this means you will be buying a new server any time soon, but I wanted to point out that not fitting in memory is not a technical issue.